# ls command adding quotes in bash script

Tags: bash, scripting, ls

I have a folder named folder1 with directories test.mp3 and test.mp4.

I have a bash script that looks like this

```
ORIGINATION_PATH=folder1
ext=mp*
files=($(ls "$ORIGINATION_PATH"/test/$ext))
for f in "${files[@]}"
do
    echo f
done
```

I want my files array to contain test.mp3 and test.mp4 but I get the following error because the script wraps my ls command path in qoutes:`ls: cannot access 'folder1/test/mp*': No such file or directory`

Comment: This is why you [don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)...

Comment: What are you [**actually trying to do?**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)  All the code in your question can be replaced by: `printf '%s\n' folder1/test/*.mp*`

Comment: (Your `echo` command is incorrect also, by the way.  You'll just get a bunch of `f`s.)

Answer (score 4):

Your code error is that you didn't put a `*.` in front of `$ext`

```
files=($(ls "$ORIGINATION_PATH"/test/*.$ext))
```

However, as @jasonwryan points out, [don't parse ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

In this case you don't need `ls` at all:

```
files=("$ORIGINATION_PATH"/test/*.$ext)
```

or

```
for f in "$ORIGINATION_PATH"/test/*.$ext
```

and let globbing work for you.

Answer (score 3):

Replace:

```
files=($(ls "$ORIGINATION_PATH"/test/$ext))
```

With:

```
files=("$ORIGINATION_PATH"/test/*.$ext)
```

#### Example

Consider these files:

```
$ ls folder1/test/*
folder1/test/test.mp3  folder1/test/test.mp4
```

This glob fails to match any file:

```
$ ls folder1/test/mp*
ls: cannot access 'folder1/test/mp*': No such file or directory
```

This is because neither `test.mp3` nor `test.mp4` matches the glob `mp*`.

By contrast, this glob matches both:

```
$ ls folder1/test/*.mp*
folder1/test/test.mp3  folder1/test/test.mp4
```

This captures all the matching files in an array:

```
$ files=("$ORIGINATION_PATH"/test/*.$ext)
$ declare -p files
declare -a files='([0]="folder1/test/test.mp3" [1]="folder1/test/test.mp4")'
```